# How can i apply 'set -e' for child process?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I use bash shell script in my project.

Main script call many sub scripts, but sometimes sub script has error.
I want script stop immediately.

I found `-errexit` option. It will works for me.

There are constraints. I can't edit sub scripts.
plus, i don't want to touch exec line.

Lower is example.

```
#!/bin/bash

# do something

exec bash test.sh
```

test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

cat as.txt  # error
cat ab.txt  # run
```

I want `cat ab.txt` not be run.

I know, `exex bash -e test.sh` will run.
but real project code is this, touch exec line is dangerous.

```
exec "$@"
```

I can't expect what is `$@`.

If i write `set -e` in 'do something', it's not apply in child process(test.sh).

I can change default option script, like `~/.bashrc` ?
How can i apply shell option for child process?

Please help me!

Comment: Don't use `set -e`; just test the exit status your self and exit if necessary. `cat as.txt || exit`.

Comment: @chepner sadly, I can't edit test.sh. I can only edit main bash shell script.

Comment: What does "touch exec line is dangerous" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution.

```
export SHELLOPTS
```

This answer helped me.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/387186/are-all-the-shell-options-not-inherited-by-scripts

Answer (score 0):

I've used a similar example and the script with the do something exited right away after the cat command didn't succeed.

doSome.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

exec bash test.sh
```

test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

cat text.txt
touch newfile
```

output:

[image: command output]

maybe you don't need to use `set -e`?

EDIT:

the file was created:

```
$ ll newfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 0000 0000 0 Sep 14 13:57 newfile
```

and when replacing `touch newfile` with a `cat` operation it does keep going and the issue persists.

a working solution might be adding error handling on a per-line basis:

test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

cat text.txt || exit 1
cat nofile.txt || exit 1
```

Comment: I think, ```touch newfile``` is run.
how about write ```cat text.txt``` two times? I think it will run two times.